# cantor middle thirds set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, integration

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by letting $f = 0 $ on $\mathcal{C}$, the Cantor set and $f(x) = k $ for every $x$ in each interval of lenght $\frac{1}{3^k}$ which has been removed from $[0,1]$. We want to calculate $\int\limits_{[0,1]} f dm $.

How CAn I express $f$ as a simple function?

So, if $$f(x) = \sum_{k}^{\infty} \sum_{j = 1}^{2^{k-1} } k 1_{A_{kj}}$$, then

$$\int\limits_{[0,1]} f dm = \sum_{k}^{\infty} \sum_{j = 1}^{2^{k-1} } k m(A_{kj}) = \sum_{k}^{\infty} \sum_{j = 1}^{2^{k-1} } \frac{k}{3^k} = \sum_{k}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k-1}k}{3^k} = 3 $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is a point-wise limit of simple functions as you keep removing more and more intervals. In fact, these simple functions increase point-wise to $f$, so you can use the monotone convergence theorem to evaluate the limiting integral.

In each round, you remove $2^{k-1}$ intervals of length $1/3^k$, so that the integral of the resulting simple function up until that round is $$\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{j\times2^{j-1}}{3^j},$$ since, for each $j\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, there are $2^{j-1}$ subintervals of length $1/3^j$, and the value of the function is $j$ on each of these intervals. The monotone convergence theorem then implies that $$\int_{[0,1]}f\,\mathrm{d}m=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{j\times 2^{j-1}}{3^j}=3.$$

Comment: My book says as a hint that we can write $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k 2^{k-1} 1_{A_k} $. But I dont see why this is true? can you help see why this is true ? thanks

Comment: The complement of the Cantor set consists of the following intervals:
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{llll}
(1/3,2/3)&&&\\
(1/9,2/9)&(7/9,8/9)&&\\
(1/27,2/27)&(7/27,8/27)&(19/27,20/27)&(25/27,26/27)\\
\vdots&&&
\end{array}
\end{align*}
and so forth. The general pattern is that for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, there are $2^{k-1}$ intervals of length $1/3^k$, as I outlined above for $k\in\{1,2,3\}$. The value of the function $f$ on each of these intervals is $k$.

Comment: suppose $x \in A_2$ where $A_2$ is the union of the two intervals removed at 2nd stage, then $f(x) = 4 \neq 2 $ which is how $f$ is defined in the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the hint in the book is slightly misleading. A more appropriate representation of $f$ would be as follows. Let $A_{kj}$ be an interval of length $1/3^k$ for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ and $j\in\{1,\ldots,2^{k-1}\}$. For example, $A_{3,2}=(7/27,8/27)$ according to the enumeration presented in my previous comment. Then, for any $x\in[0,1]$, $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{k-1}}k\times\mathbf{1}_{A_{kj}}(x).$$

Comment: look at my update of the solution. Seems like we can solve the integral without using monotone convergence theorem and just using the definition of $f$ you gave in your last comment. IS this correct?

Comment: The problem is that $f$ is not a simple function, because any simple function must be a _finite_ linear combination of characteristic functions. Here, $f$ is an _infinite_ linear combination of characteristic functions, so that it is not a simple function. You can express it as the pointwise limit of a pointwise increasing sequence of genuine simple functions, but in order to interchange the limit and the integral operators, you need to refer to the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: how about if we say $ \int f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k}^{n} \sum_{j = 1}^{2^{k-1} } k m(A_{kj}) $

Comment: We can do the following:
\begin{align*}
&\,\int_{[0,1]}f\,\mathrm{d}m=\int_{[0,1]}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{k-1}}k\times\mathbf{1}_{A_{kj}}\,\mathrm{d}m\\
=&\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{k-1}}k{\times}\mathbf{1}_{A_{kj}}\,\mathrm{d}m=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{k-1}}k\times\int_{[0,1]}\mathbf{1}_{A_{kj}}\,\mathrm{d}m\\=&\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{k-1}}k\times m(A_{kj})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{k-1}}k\times\frac{1}{3^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{k-1}\times k}{3^k}=3.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_k$ be the $k-th$ set deleted from the construction of $C$. Then $f = \sum k \chi_{E_k}$.

Comment: This is not a simple function, because a simple function must be a _finite_ linear combination of characteristic functions.

Comment: The range of $f$ is infinite, one cannot write $f$ as a simple function.